# XSL format-number without rounding

Tags: xslt, rounding

Is there anything similar to format-number in XSL that could take a number and format it like '#0.00' and not round it?

So,

- 5 would become 5.00
- 14.6 would become 14.60
- 1.375 would become 1.37

Just format-number doesn't work because it would round 1.375 to 1.38

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(MY_NUMBER, '#0.00')" />
```

This concatenation substring mess won't work for 5 (because there is no ".") and won't add a zero to the end of 14.6

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(MY_NUMBER,'.'), '.',  substring(substring-after(MY_NUMBER,'.'),1,2))" />
```

I'm I going to have to do a messy:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=""></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you are restricted to XSLT 1 so something like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="/">
:
<xsl:call-template name="f">
<xsl:with-param name="n" select="5"/>
</xsl:call-template>
:
<xsl:call-template name="f">
<xsl:with-param name="n" select="14.6"/>
</xsl:call-template>
:
<xsl:call-template name="f">
<xsl:with-param name="n" select="1.375"/>
</xsl:call-template>
:
<xsl:call-template name="f">
<xsl:with-param name="n" select="-12.1234"/>
</xsl:call-template>
:
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="f">
<xsl:param name="n"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($n*1000) div 1000, '#0.00')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces

```
:
5.00
:
14.60
:
1.38
:
-12.12
:
```

Comment: Perfect! Not sure how that extra <xsl:value-of select="<xsl:value-of got there, so i removed it so as not to confuse anyone.

Comment: @sigmapi13 OK I removed fro here as well , note following sentence also needs to go i that case

Comment: The solution David Carlisle provided does not quite work if there are negative numbers.
Imagine following numbers:
`12.1234`, `-12.1234` and `12`. If used in xslt that David has provided, the outcome will be `12.12`, `-12.13` and `12.00`. So the double which includes a negative number would actually round. To prevent this, you need to multiply by a thousand (floor($n*1000) div 1000, .... ). @DavidCarlisle, fyi..